# How can I export a block of codes from Jupyter Notebook to text file?

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a deep learning structure that I want to export a text file so it will ease everything for me.

This is a jupyter notebook code block:

```
In [7]:
def fDNN(in_dim, out_dim):
    # Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(210, input_dim=in_dim, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(70, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(out_dim, activation='softmax'))

    # Compilation
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
           metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Output of this block should be written in a text file same as above:

```
        # Model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(210, input_dim=in_dim, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(70, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(out_dim, activation='softmax'))

        # Compilation
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
               metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

After the cell with `def fDNN()` was run, it will be possible to run this code.
The output will be the content of all already `run/executed` cells.

```
gb = fDNN.__globals__
#print(len(gb["In"]))

for item,ea in enumerate(gb["In"]):
    print("\n-------- In[", str(item), "]  ---------")
    print(ea)
    # check for somethin in `ea`
    # can decide to write the content of `ea` to file
```

Hope this will help you get going to do something you want.

Comment: I have sorted it out by using a library which causes "code reflection". Does that make sense?